# Issue when installing kubectl on window 10 home

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to install kubectl v1.16.0 downloaded from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows) on my window 10 Home follow the instruction on kubernetes.io, I've added the enviroment variable but when I openning cmd and type kubectl I got the error as [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWkjl.png)

and this is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcv7i.png) after clicked close button

I'm not sure it relates to Window 10 Home or not, anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: What `kubectl` binary do you use ?

Comment: Please provide error messages directly as text, instead of linking to screen shots.

Comment: @EFrank The error: "This app cant run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, please check with software publisher .

Comment: @mario I downloaded it from here, the lastest version v1.16.0
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows

Comment: @mario I downloaded it from here, the lastest version v1.16.0
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're using the proper binary intended for your system. If you follow the instructions under [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows) link everything should work fine.

If the binary is correct and your system keeps saying `access is denied` when you try to run it, make sure it is not a **permission issue**. Try to put it in another folder to which you have full access like your `Desktop`, `Downloads` etc.

You can try to **run it from command line** by providing full path to the binary. If it runs properly it means that you probably don't have sufficient permissions to a folder `C:\Windows\system32`. It is actually not a good idea to keep your application binaries there as it is a system folder and it is very likely that you may not have sufficient permissions to it as a normal user. More on this folder and its purpose in a Windows system you can read in [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-system32/) article.

You can also refer to [this](https://windowsreport.com/access-is-denied-windows-10/) article describing **how to fix "Access is denied" issue on Windows 10** but don't do it with `C:\Windows\system32` directory. Better put your `kubectl` binary in other place and [add a path to it to your PATH environment variable](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: how can I know if proper binary intended to my system, I'm trying to install the lastest version  v1.16.0

Comment: Where did you download it from ? Please show me the link. Version can be proper but maybe it is intended for a different system.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows
I download it from here "Download the latest release v1.16.0 from this link."

Comment: @Dat Lam, so what happens when you simply run this kubectl.exe binary let's say when it is on your `desktop` or `Downloads` folder ? Any error message ?

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't works, I tried to put the binary into downloads folder, also tried to run it from command line,  the same error ""This app cant run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, please check with software publisher"
Maybe something went wrong with my window

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't works, I tried to put the binary into downloads folder, also tried to run it from command line,  the same error ""This app cant run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, please check with software publisher"
Maybe something went wrong with my window

Comment: Just to double check if your binary isn't corrupted please download it again from here: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.16.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe and try to run it.

Comment: One other thing came to my mind... Could you run command `systeminfo | findstr Type` and post its output ?

Comment: the output of that command are 
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
System Type:               x64-based PC

Comment: oh, I downloaded your file and its worked, is there any chances that the file on the kubernetes home page was corrupted?

Comment: "Type: x64-based PC" - I even thought that you may have 32-bit system and trying to run `kubectl` version that is intended for 64-bit, which is the default. As to corrupted binary on the kubernetes website I don't think so. I also downloaded it from there and it worked. Maybe it just wasn't downloaded properly the first time. Did you compare the size of both files ? Anyway, I'm glad it finally works.